# Generating a graph from a random set of edges

Tags: graph

I have an array of edges as follows in some random order

```
edges = [e1 e2 e3...en]
```

I have now generated a set of nodes by testing two edges against each other

```
nodes = []
for edge1 in edges:
    for edge2 in edges:
        if edge1 == edge2 continue
        nodes.append[create_node(edge1, edge2)]
```

What I need to do is to now create a graph connecting the nodes an edges. Something like this:

[Graph Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyChD.png)

However, in this case I only have a set of edges as you can see, and I have created a set of nodes where I know each of the two parent edges. As you can see, each edge can be a part of two nodes.

I'm not exactly sure how to approach this problem

Comment: what you want to do with the graph? some of the problems can be solved with whatever data you have

Comment: I wish to use the graph to measure the size of the box for example. With the graph, I also know the angle between the edges. With the graph, the points become ordered

Comment: check how the graph structure is maintained in http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-23-bellman-ford-algorithm/, if you add the set of nodes you have created above, you get the easy traversal in edges and collection of nodes handy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming node has below structure

```
class Node{
  String name;
  List<Node> friendNodes = new ArrayList();
}
```

1. Instantiate a Map of `<node name: Node>`,  let name be nodeMap. Keep it empty as of now.
2. Iterate through list of edges. For edge e1, nodes are n1 and n2.

   - Check if nodes n1 and n2 are present in nodeMap. If absent add to the
     nodeMap;
   - If edge is directed, suppose from n1 to n2, then add n2 to friendNodes of node n1;
   - If edge is undirected, add n2 to friendNodes of node n1 and add n1 friendNodes of node n2.